# How to open all links that contains specific link in a new tab with java script

Tags: javascript, browser, console

i want to open all link with specific link but my code just opens first link not all links
code is runes in browser console

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0, l = links.length; i < l; i++) {
  var link = links[i];
  if (link.href.indexOf("test.com") !== -1) {
      console.log(link);
    window.open(link, '_blank');
  }
}
```

how can open all links is it impossible to do that from browser console?

Answer (score 0):

In `window.open` you have to put `href`.

You can try this:

```
const specificUrl = "example.com";
const links = document.querySelectorAll("a");

for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  if (links[i].href.includes(specificUrl)) {
    window.open(links[i].href, "_blank");
  }
}
```

Comment: your code is working but just open first link and not opens the same links

Comment: Since the page has multiple same site links and because of that the browser blocks opening of all the links together. It's happening because of the browser policy to block pop-ups and redirects. If you run the code, you will see a "Popups Blocked" prompt in the URL bar.

Comment: Do you want all such links to open automatically or on click?
Ideally, it's better to do this on click because otherwise it will be blocked by the browser.

Comment: no, it's not showing popups blocked or other prompts it just opens the first link
I think I should use a macro recorder or something :)